# Youtube V3 API - Channel api filtered by categoryId zero result

Tags: google-api, youtube, youtube-api

Is there something wrong with the **categoryId** for the channel API? It seems like it's not working. It doesn't provide any error however it returns zero result.

Here is the link I testing:

> https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/channels?key={API KEY}&part=snippet&categoryId=GCR2FtaW5n&maxResults=3

Comment: zero results means that there is no data.

Comment: @DaImTo Ofcourse it means there is no data. However, does it mean that the categoryId for the channel is not working? cuz I tried every GuideCategory and all of them return zero result. I'm not sure if i just did something wrong.

Comment: @user3779015 I get the same results too, maybe the categoryId is not working, but,  with this request, what you are trying to achieve?, return all gaming channel videos or seomthing similar?

Comment: @MauricioAriasOlave I was planning to get all the channels that are categorized as gaming. However, since this is not working what I did is just get the videos with categoryId = 20 then i just get the channels from there.

Comment: @user3779015 I understand. I hope you want share your solution and answer you own question. Thank you.